# Java: OutOfMemoryError Exception and freeMemory()

Tags: java, exception, memory, out-of-memory

I have the following test program:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{       
    HashMap<Integer, String> hm = new HashMap<Integer,String>(); 
    int i = 1;  
    while(true)
    {
        hm.put(i, "blah");
        i++;
        System.out.println("############"); 
        System.out.println("Max mem: " + Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()); 
        System.out.println("Total mem: " + Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()); 
        System.out.println("Free mem:" + Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
    }
}
```

If I run this program, I get the follwing output:

```
...

    ############
    Max mem: 8060928

    Total mem: 8060928

    Free mem:334400

    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.HashMap.addEntry(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.HashMap.put(Unknown Source)
        at Test.main(Test.java:14)
```

Why I get an "OutOfMemoryError" Exception although the method freeMemory() returns that there is more free memory??? If there a way to use all the freeMemory()?

Answer (score 5):

The `HashMap` class resizes on occasion as the number of entries in it grows.  Even though you are showing 300+K left free, that may not be enough to handle the resizing of the hash buckets.

```
void resize(int newCapacity) {
    Entry[] oldTable = table;
    int oldCapacity = oldTable.length;
    if (oldCapacity == MAXIMUM_CAPACITY) {
        threshold = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        return;
    }
    // ***possible big allocation here***
    Entry[] newTable = new Entry[newCapacity];
    transfer(newTable);
    table = newTable;
    threshold = (int)(newCapacity * loadFactor);
}
```

In a more general sense, fine grained expectations over the heap memory (and overall process size) is not recommended in Java.  There are background allocations as well as objects in the heap that have yet to be reclaimed that take up space that you may not have anticipated.  In addition, the garbage collector uses progressively more and more CPU as it approaches a full heap.  You want to run with plenty of memory overhead above your expected maximum allocation size.

Answer (score 4):

1. [Runtime.freeMemory() javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#freeMemory%28%29)  says that is returns `"an approximation to the total amount of memory currently available for future allocated objects"`
2. The way all dynamic structures work is that they allocate memory in chunks. When `HashMap` is getting full it doesn't allocate extra space for just one more object. It allocates a chunk of some size. I do not know the exact way it works in JVM, but it may try to allocate as much as twice the amount of current memory it uses.

Answer (score 1):

You will be getting the out of memory exception at the point where the HashMap need to expand it's internal storage. The requirement for this will be greater than the available feel memory.

Comment: But when I use LinkedList instead of HashMap, I get the same problem. In my real context, I want to read 10 millions data records, each of them is a HashMap and I store all HashMaps in a LinkedList. And jvisualvm tells me, that my program can use max. 80GB, but it uses only 65GB. At this point I get the exception...

Comment: @user1053813, You can do this, but you will need to give your application a lot of memory, many GBs I suspect.  Memory is pretty cheap these days so that doesn't have to be a problem.  If you want the data to be stored more efficiently I would use objects instead of HashMap. (which can be 2-3x smaller) It is possible there is some sort of OS related memory barrier preventing you using more than 64 GB in one application. You might consider using direct memory to store the data, this can be as much as half the size of objects and use very little heap but is much more work. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like amount of free memory is not enough to run the JVM.